# Cannot convert structure in a byte array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, structure

I'm having problems while converting these structures to a byte array:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
/// <summary>
/// Packet structure, type 1 (SEND)
/// </summary>
internal struct PACKET_SEND
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Packet Type: 0 for notifications, 1 for status, 2 for login and auth.
    /// </summary>
    public Byte Type;
    /// <summary>
    /// Packet Key: select it from Packets class.
    /// </summary>
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 61)]
    public char[] Key;
    /// <summary>
    /// Account Name.
    /// </summary>
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 30)]
    public char[] AccountName;
    /// <summary>
    /// Account Status: 0 for offline, 1 for online, 2 for absent, 3 for busy, 4 for invisible.
    /// </summary>
    public Byte Status;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
/// <summary>
/// Packet structure, type 2 (RECV)
/// </summary>
internal struct PACKET_RECV
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Packet Type: 0 for notifications, 1 for status, 2 for login and auth.
    /// </summary>
    public Byte Type;
    /// <summary>
    /// Packet Key: select it from Packets class.
    /// </summary>
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 61)]
    public char[] Key;
    /// <summary>
    /// Account Name.
    /// </summary>
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 30)]
    public char[] AccountName;
}
```

Using these functions:

```
public static T ByteArrayToStructure<T>(byte[] data) where T : struct
    {
        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        T stuff = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(),
            typeof(T));
        handle.Free();
        return stuff;
    }

    public static byte[] StructToByteArray(object structure)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(structure)];
        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(structure, handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), false);//HERE GETS EXCEPTION
        handle.Free();
        return buffer;
    }
```

I'm getting that exception while using "StructToByteArray" method:

```
Type could not be marshaled because the length of an embedded array instance does not match the declared length in the layout.
```

Ideas? Please, don't post only the solution but the explaination would be more appreciated :D.
Greetings.

Comment: Sure that you did it right? I made a quick test and it worked for me. Can you show some more code? Btw my original code didn't show this ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704161/c-sharp-array-within-a-struct/8704505#8704505 ) but i recommed to wrap the `Marshal` calls into `try ... finally`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See ...

[Error : Type could not be marshaled because the length of an embedded array instance does not match the declared length in the layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845514/error-type-could-not-be-marshaled-because-the-length-of-an-embedded-array-inst)

... and ...

[Error on size of class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416954/error-on-size-of-class)

... maybe you don't initialize the array fields "Key" & "AccountName" or you don't initialize them correctly. The values always have to be 61 respectively 30 chars in size.

Comment: Trying that. I'm sure that the Key is **always** 61 char length but AccountName is variable. So going to "fill" and try.

Comment: @Ciavi Did you try to convert the array separate? Because this should not work, converting the hole struct is working.